# Is there any way to find how long an animation will take?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want my code to find the amount of time that it takes a deleteRowsAtIndexPaths animation to animate. Is there any way to find this?

Comment: Why are you interested in this? Do you want to kick off something after the animation has completed?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. You have to run the animation on the device and time it manually, if you need such information.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way to do this. Atleast you could give the following a try.

If you save a timestamp just before calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withAnimation` and then call [`didTransitionToState:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/editingStyle) on the UITableCell you would be able to compare two timestamps and see the difference and thereby the duration of the animation.